# git push [remote rejected] (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git-push

remote: [--------Check the extension------]
remote: GL-HOOK-ERR: Unable to submit the extension file: ['java/gamebase-main/gamebasesdk/src/main/cpp/arm64-v8a/libopencv_java3.so']
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gitlab-rd0.maezia.com:31755/gamebase/gamebaseai/gamebase-gamebaseai-soundeffectdetection.git'
To ssh://gitlab-rd0.maezia.com:31755/gamebase/gamebaseai/gamebase-gamebaseai-soundeffectdetection.git
!   refs/heads/dev_likun_release_2:refs/heads/dev_likun_release_2   [remote rejected] (pre-receive hook declined)

git push --force not work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a pre-receive hook on your Gitlab server, which is preventing the push.

Unfortunately the error message is custom-made by the hook authors, and it's sort of confusing, so I can't exactly divine what it wants to convey.

Anyway, you should talk to the administrators/maintainers of your Gitlab server, they'll be able to provide more information.